# Update UITableView with new item in array

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a simple `tableview` that's displaying a `NSMutableArray`, but when a item is added I need to do a **`[self.tableView reloadData]`**;
How do I make the UITableView to update when the array is updated, like if I use the `CoreData` (`NSFetchedResultControlerDelegate` i think it is that does the updates).

Or do I need to accept the **`reloadData`** call on everyplace that's updating the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code

```
// adding new data to array.
[mArray addObject:@"abc"];

// Figure out where that item is in the array
int lastRow = [mArray count]-1;

// Create the corresponding index path
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0];

// Insert this new row into the table
[[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip]
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

**Note :**

The important thing to keep in mind when using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` is that your `UITableViewDataSource` needs to match what the insert is telling it to do. If you add a row to the tableview, make sure the backing data is already updated to match.

**Further Reference**

[Apple Developer Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)